# Unable to locate publishable resources installing jwt-auth with composer

Tags: php, laravel, jwt, composer-php, laravel-6

I' trying to install `jwt-aut` on a laravel 6 project using composer, this is composer.json

```
{
    "name": "laravel/laravel",
    "type": "project",
    "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
    "keywords": [
        "framework",
        "laravel"
    ],
    "license": "MIT",
    "require": {
        "php": "^7.2.5|^8.0",
        "fideloper/proxy": "^4.4",
        "laravel/framework": "^6.20",
        "laravel/tinker": "^2.5",
        "tymon/jwt-auth": "^1.0"
    },
```

and I added this line to providers array in app.php

```
Tymon\JWTAuth\Providers\LaravelServiceProvider::class,
```

I executed cpmposer.install  but following the doc instructions I execute

```
php artisan vendor:publish --provider="Tymon\JWTAuth\Providers\LaravelServiceProvider"
```

but I get

```
Unable to locate publishable resources.
Publishing complete.
```

I'm stuck here

Answer (score 0):

Try Run
`php artisan clear-compiled` and
`composer dumpautoload`

And re run your publish

Comment: I get tat: `In ProviderRepository.php line 208:
                                                                    
  Class 'Tymon\JWTAuth\Providers\LaravelServiceProvider' not found`